# como poner php o html en fwrite?

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un mini sistema para crear un folder con archivos adentro.
pero quiero que los archivos tengan como codigo html y php adentro cuando sea creado.

el problema es que no encuentro informacion para poderme ayudar? alguien me podria ayudar?

Codigo:

```html
<?php  
    $dirname = $_POST["name"];  
    $filename = "{$dirname}";  
    
    if (file_exists($filename)) {  
        echo "El nombre de usuario {$dirname} Ya existe";  
    } else {  
        mkdir("users/{$dirname}", 0777);  
 $content = "Nombre:".$_POST["name"]." Direccion:".$_POST["address"]; 
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/index.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/archivo.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion_cambiar.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion_eliminararchivos.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion_fotoperfil.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/eliminararchivos.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/eliminarcuenta.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/eliminarfoto.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/enviado.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/login.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/panel.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/perfilcorrecto.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/salir.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/subir", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/validar.php", "w");
 fwrite($fp,$content); 
 fclose($fp); 
        echo "Tu cuenta {$dirname} Fue creado correctamente.";  
    }


?>  

 <?php
$fp = fopen("{users/$dirname}/index.php", "w") or die("Error al intentar abrir el archivo!");
$txt = "test\n";
fwrite($fp, $txt);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el siguiente ejemplo creo un script PHP a partir del actual y lo ejecuto:

```
<?php

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create a PHP file to print a message, if it don't exist
    //
    $file_path = "xxx.php";
    if (! file_exists($file_path)) {
        echo "El archivo \"$file_path\" no existe. Creando... <br>";

        if ($archivo = fopen($file_path, "a")) {
            $cotent = "<?php" . PHP_EOL
                . "echo 'Hello world <br>';" . PHP_EOL;

            if (fwrite($archivo, $cotent)) {
                echo "Cotenido guardado <br>";
            } else {
                echo "Error guardando contenido <br>";
            }

            fclose($archivo);
        }
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Load and run the PHP file created
    //
    if (file_exists($file_path)) {
        require $file_path;
    } else {
        echo "El archivo no existe";
    }
```

El resultado de la primera ejecución será:

```
El archivo "xxx.php" no existe. Creando... 
Cotenido guardado 
Hello world
```

y de las siguientes:

```
Hello world
```

> Editado

Para hacer esto en un nuevo directorio tendrás que crearlo y darle permisos de escritura y lectura.

Comment: gracias por publicar su respuesta, ya encontre la manera de poner html en el fwrite pero ahora tengo un problema en php. pero al poner el codigo php en el fwrite la pagina no funciona, aparece todo en blanco. pero al quitar el codigo vuelve a la normalidad. me podrias ayudar en eso?

Comment: `<?php 

    $files = scandir('archivos');
    for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++) {
     ?>
     <p>
 <a class='archivo' download='<?php echo $files[$a] ?>' href='archivos/<?php echo $files[$a] ?>'><?php echo $files[$a] ?></a>
        </p>
     <?php
    }
    ?>`

Comment: @danielmeza esto debes ponerlo en una nueva pregunta. Vota mi respuesta si te ha sido útil. Un saludo.